# How to get variable from url in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Im using laravel 5.1. I've given my users a promocode url so they will come to my site with a url like http://www.xxxxx.com/?promo=123456.

Within the blade itself I have a hidden input with a isset to check if that variable exists or not but when I submit the form. No data passes through to the controller for the promo.

Heres my code for the form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="{{ route('something') }}" class="something" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="promo" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" value="{{ isset($promo) ? $promo : 'Default' }}">
</form>
```

Not sure what I've missed.

Comment: What does your route definition and controller action that handles the route look like?

Comment: My controller action is basically `$promo = $request->input('promo'); dd();` once the form posts and my route is simply `Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'SomeController@index']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you don't have the `name` attribute in the input:

```
<input name='promo' type="hidden" id="promo" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" value="{{ isset($promo) ? $promo : 'Default' }}">
```

Then in your controller get it with:

```
$request->input('promo');
```

Comment: Wow cant believe I missed name. Thanks that fixed half the problem. But now all I get in the controller when I `dd();` is "Default". Would you know why its not actually getting the `?promo=123456`

Comment: in your form, your `$promo` variable where does it come from ?

Comment: I'm trying to get it from the URL. I give it to users as `something.com/?promo=123456`. My goal is to be able to get that promo code from the url and store it.

Comment: you have to get the parameter in the controller, then pass the parameter from the controller to the view with the form

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks alot!